# Dynamic Dependent Select Box using Jquery and Ajax in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm new with coding and I found some really valuable information that could help my register form look better using Ajax.
The problem is that, even though the php files are working fine, I think that the js file is not doing it's job. here:
in the register form there's this:

`<?php
    include 'php_includes/conexion.php'; (connect to DB users)
    include 'php_includes/conexionlugar.php'; (connect to DB states/cities)
?>`

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

in the form there's this:

***Select State***

```
<select name="departamento" id="departamento">
<option value="">Seleccione Departamento</option>
<?php echo cargar_departamentos();?>
</select>
```

***Select City***

```
<select name="provincia" id="provincia">
<option value="">Seleccione Provincia</option>
</select>
```

Now, in the conexionlugar.php (tested/working):

`<?php
    function cargar_departamentos()
    {
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "lugar");
        $output = '';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM departamentos ORDER BY NOMBRE_DEPA";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $output = '<option value="'.$row["IDDEPARTAMENTOS"].'">'.$row["NOMBRE_DEPA"].'</option>';
            echo "$output";
        }
    }
        return $output;
?>`

in the jquery.js (don't know much about this :()

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#departamento').change(function(){
        var IDDEPARTAMENTOS = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'../php_includes/fetch_provincia.php',
            type:"POST",
            data:{departamentoId:IDDEPARTAMENTOS},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#provincia').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});`

in the fetch_provincia.php (tested/working)

`<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "lugar");
    $output ='';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM provincias WHERE departamentos_IDDEPARTAMENTOS = '".$_POST["departamentoId"]."' ORDER BY NOMBRE_PROV";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $output = '<option value="">Seleccione Provincia</option>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $output = '<option value="'.$row["IDPROVINCIAS"].'">'.$row["NOMBRE_PROV"].'</option>';
        echo $output;
    }
    return $output;
?>`

Though separately the PHP files are working, the JS file changing departamentoId for IDDEPARTAMENTOS looks like it's not... help me please.

**I think I fixed it, deleting the "return" on both php and adding the js to the same page and not calling it through**

Answer (score 0):

The data you are sending from php needs to be sent as json. I would actually not do the "formatting" in php. Just return $result:

echo json_encode($result);

then in your js file, just iterate through "data" and create the options:

success:function(data)
            {
                $.each(data, function(key, val){
    console.log("Key: " + key + " val: " + val);
    }
            }

Answer (score 0):

have a some errors in your code.

First, in "cargar_departamentos", the return it´s out of a function, and in your fetch_provincia.php, not need a return statement.

In your jQuery code, try remove one of both jQuery called in your head, and Change de dataType directive of "text" to HTML.

Answer (score -1):

@gilgameshbk you are calling jquery 2 times in your head

maybe this may cause some conflict.